# Ejabberd Closes BOSH session after available presence

Tags: javascript, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, jsjac

I can't figure out why Ejabberd (14.07 & 14.12) is Closing a BOSH session after receiving an 'available' stanza for that same session.

I am using JsJac as web client lib and the session is being prebound server side and JsJac is doing 'inherit' on first page load and als on restart. The scenario in which this happens is after a successful connection and chat, i disable the network connection using chrome developer tools.

Ejabberd pings every 15 Seconds and is set to 'kill' on timeout. The Inactivity_timeout for BOSH in ejabberd.yml is set to 480.

The user can then click a link to try to reconnect. This is calling the exact same function as the initial prebind+client side inherit. After seemingly successful reconnect, a few seconds later, this:

`Close session for 
anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0@localhost/7f317c7fcbb9fb1b79c414c2d8afe05c`

appears in the ejabberd log and a stanza of unavailable is sent to the other party in the chat.

Question: anybody have any idea why the BOSH session might be closed?

Here is the relevant piece of the Ejabberd log

```
2015-01-09 18:25:21.308 [debug] <0.2710.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:343 Received XML on stream = <<"<presence from=\"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0@jaxlecho.localhost\" type=\"available\"/>">>
2015-01-09 18:25:21.309 [debug] <0.2710.0>@shaper:update:117 State: {maxrate,50000,1899.4311619841992,1420824321273332}, Size=97
M=0.9887812185897407, I=35.836
2015-01-09 18:25:21.390 [info] <0.2709.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:313 (#Port<0.41723>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:58483 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2015-01-09 18:25:21.391 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http:init:145 S: [{[<<"presence">>],mod_webpresence},{[<<"captcha">>],ejabberd_captcha},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind},{[<<"http-poll">>],ejabberd_http_poll}]
2015-01-09 18:25:21.391 [info] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http:init:149 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.41723>}
2015-01-09 18:25:21.392 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:277 (#Port<0.41723>) http query: 'POST' /http-bind
2015-01-09 18:25:21.392 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http:process_request:438 client data: <<"<body rid='876185' sid='a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19'/>">>
2015-01-09 18:25:21.392 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http:process:350 [<<"http-bind">>] matches [<<"http-bind">>]
2015-01-09 18:25:21.393 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http:process:354 [{'Accept-Language',<<"en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,und;q=0.4,nl;q=0.2,ca;q=0.2">>},{'Accept-Encoding',<<"gzip, deflate">>},{'Referer',<<"http://localhost:9080/">>},{'Accept',<<"*/*">>},{'Content-Type',<<"text/xml; charset=UTF-8">>},{'User-Agent',<<"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36">>},{<<"Origin">>,<<"http://localhost:9080">>},{'Content-Length',<<"158">>},{'Connection',<<"close">>},{'Host',<<"vagrant.localhost">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:21.393 [debug] <0.5331.0>@mod_http_bind:process:68 Incoming data: <body rid='876185' sid='a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19'/>
2015-01-09 18:25:21.393 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:parse_request:1128 --- incoming data --- 
<body rid='876185' sid='a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19'/>
 --- END --- 
2015-01-09 18:25:21.394 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:792 Looking for session: <<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>
2015-01-09 18:25:21.394 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:440 New request: {http_put,876185,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"876185">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>},{<<"key">>,<<"38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19">>}],[],158,1,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58483}}
2015-01-09 18:25:21.395 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:575 New request: {http_put,876185,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"876185">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>},{<<"key">>,<<"38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19">>}],[],158,1,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58483}}
2015-01-09 18:25:21.395 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:rid_allow:866 Previous rid / New rid: 876184/876185
2015-01-09 18:25:21.396 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:608 Actually processing request: {http_put,876185,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"876185">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>},{<<"key">>,<<"38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19">>}],[],158,1,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58483}}
2015-01-09 18:25:21.396 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:619 Key/OldKey/NextKey: 38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19/85e12ff1c2c9590328a5f0a1e58c14e52a8c6c42/85e12ff1c2c9590328a5f0a1e58c14e52a8c6c42
2015-01-09 18:25:21.397 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:659  -- SaveKey: 38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19
2015-01-09 18:25:21.397 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:671 reqlist: [{hbr,876185,<<"85e12ff1c2c9590328a5f0a1e58c14e52a8c6c42">>,[]},{hbr,876184,<<"85e12ff1c2c9590328a5f0a1e58c14e52a8c6c42">>,[{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0@jaxlecho.localhost">>},{<<"to">>,<<"agent1@localhost/cb_operator_1420818758533">>},{<<"type">>,<<"available">>},{<<"show">>,<<"chat">>}],[]}}]}]
2015-01-09 18:25:21.398 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:717 really sending now: []
2015-01-09 18:25:31.193 [debug] <0.2648.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:322 route
    from {jid,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    to {jid,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"get">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.194 [debug] <0.2648.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    to {jid,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"4293"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.194 [debug] <0.2648.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:514 session manager
    from {jid,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    to {jid,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"4293"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.194 [debug] <0.2648.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:612 sending to process <0.4053.0>
2015-01-09 18:25:31.195 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:914 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"to">>,<<"agent1@localhost/cb_operator_1420818758533">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"get">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.195 [debug] <0.5331.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1056  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='localhost' to='agent1@localhost/cb_operator_1420818758533' id='4293567110' type='get'><ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/></iq></body>
 --- END --- 
2015-01-09 18:25:31.228 [info] <0.2709.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:313 (#Port<0.41753>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:58484 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2015-01-09 18:25:31.230 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http:init:145 S: [{[<<"presence">>],mod_webpresence},{[<<"captcha">>],ejabberd_captcha},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind},{[<<"http-poll">>],ejabberd_http_poll}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.231 [info] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http:init:149 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.41753>}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.231 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:277 (#Port<0.41753>) http query: 'POST' /http-bind
2015-01-09 18:25:31.231 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http:process_request:438 client data: <<"<body rid='876186' sid='a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5'><iq xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"localhost\" id=\"4293567110\" type=\"result\"><ping xmlns=\"urn:xmpp:ping\"/></iq></body>">>
2015-01-09 18:25:31.231 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http:process:350 [<<"http-bind">>] matches [<<"http-bind">>]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.232 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http:process:354 [{'Accept-Language',<<"en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,und;q=0.4,nl;q=0.2,ca;q=0.2">>},{'Accept-Encoding',<<"gzip, deflate">>},{'Referer',<<"http://localhost:9080/">>},{'Accept',<<"*/*">>},{'Content-Type',<<"text/xml; charset=UTF-8">>},{'User-Agent',<<"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36">>},{<<"Origin">>,<<"http://localhost:9080">>},{'Content-Length',<<"269">>},{'Connection',<<"close">>},{'Host',<<"vagrant.localhost">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.233 [debug] <0.5332.0>@mod_http_bind:process:68 Incoming data: <body rid='876186' sid='a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="localhost" id="4293567110" type="result"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/></iq></body>
2015-01-09 18:25:31.233 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:parse_request:1128 --- incoming data --- 
<body rid='876186' sid='a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="localhost" id="4293567110" type="result"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/></iq></body>
 --- END --- 
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.5332.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:792 Looking for session: <<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:440 New request: {http_put,876186,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"876186">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>},{<<"key">>,<<"9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5">>}],[{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}],269,1,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58484}}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:575 New request: {http_put,876186,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"876186">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>},{<<"key">>,<<"9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5">>}],[{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}],269,1,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58484}}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:rid_allow:866 Previous rid / New rid: 876185/876186
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:608 Actually processing request: {http_put,876186,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"876186">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"a1e29cded4325f591bdc5b3646a8f3c78553cdd8">>},{<<"key">>,<<"9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5">>}],[{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}],269,1,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58484}}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:619 Key/OldKey/NextKey: 9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5/38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19/38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:659  -- SaveKey: 9cffab80935471f419ce5c9201475df5935108d5
2015-01-09 18:25:31.234 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:671 reqlist: [{hbr,876186,<<"38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19">>,[]},{hbr,876185,<<"38516e6b293e317ee957f6ef74fa23c68a003d19">>,[{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"to">>,<<"agent1@localhost/cb_operator_1420818758533">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"get">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}}]}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.235 [debug] <0.4052.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:717 really sending now: [{xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.235 [debug] <0.4053.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:322 route
    from {jid,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>}
    to {jid,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4293567110">>},{<<"type">>,<<"result">>}],[{xmlel,<<"ping">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:ping">>}],[]}]}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.235 [debug] <0.4053.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>,<<"agent1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"cb_operator_1420818758533">>}
    to {jid,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"loca"...>>},{<<"id">>,<<...>>},{<<...>>,...}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
2015-01-09 18:25:31.570 [info] <0.5318.0>@ejabberd_c2s:terminate:1757 ({socket_state,ejabberd_http_bind,{http_bind,<0.5317.0>,{{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},58451}},ejabberd_http_bind}) Close session for anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0@localhost/2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a
2015-01-09 18:25:31.571 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_pubsub:node_action:5143 node_action <<"pubsub.localhost">> <<"flat">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.571 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_pubsub:node_call:5124 node_call <<"flat">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.571 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_pubsub:node_action:5143 node_action <<"pubsub.localhost">> <<"hometree">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.572 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_pubsub:node_call:5124 node_call <<"hometree">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.572 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_pubsub:node_action:5143 node_action <<"pubsub.localhost">> <<"pep">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.572 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_pubsub:node_call:5124 node_call <<"pep">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">>}]
2015-01-09 18:25:31.573 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_carboncopy:disable:246 disabling for <<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">>
2015-01-09 18:25:31.574 [debug] <0.5318.0>@mod_shared_roster:unset_presence:1081 unset_presence for <<"anonymous.c6502a950667fc79c3e1534559cc02e0">> @ <<"localhost">> / <<"2b8e1ac2921d6d3713396edff70a0d2a">> -> <<>> (0 resources)
2015-01-09 18:25:31.574 [debug] <0.5318.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:322 route
```

More of the log is here. https://gist.github.com/Elexy/052a6a428fb57147bf4e

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question.

1. I had set the mod_ping to KILL the session and I believe both the BOSH connection manager and mod_ping were killing sessions. I now changed mod_ping to 'timeout_action' to 'none' and let the BOSH connection manager handle the disconnection detection.
2. The Inherit connection has to be "preloaded" with the parameters the BOSH client normally receives from the initial bosh response. In my case, relying on legacy code, the 'polling' paramater was set to 5 when the BOSH connection manager responds with 2.

JsJac was responding with up to 5 new requests within the 'requests' timeperiod of 2 seconds.

So my logic is this: mod_ping will send a ping every 15 seconds and the BOSH connection manager will check if the ping, or any other stanza is responded within 4 seconds.

Here is the initial response from the Ejabberd BOSH connection manager:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:xmpp="urn:xmpp:xbosh" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" sid="42e11a86ecba387ef5f53f5b86d38a8c7dc9ef5a" wait="300" requests="2" inactivity="480" maxpause="120" polling="2" ver="1.8" from="localhost" secure="true" authid="3627063868" xmpp:version="1.0"><stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/><sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:2"/><sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"/><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/" ver="/nWL9StXSXhEsL2wg0+s4xo/UdA="/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features></body>
```

and my, now working, JS code:

```
   args.polling = 2;
   args.inactivity = 4;
   args.requests = 2;
   args.wait = 300;

   self.connection.inherit(args);
```

p.s. after reading  http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html i set inactivity to 4 seconds in order to detect disconnections faster.